# Need to intercept the PUT calls from client with the header of manipulation

Tags: java, jetty, http-proxy

I have a written a jetty http proxy server, in that i need to intercept the PUT calls from client with the header of manipulation.

when I refer jetty there is some fixes in jetty to handle issue (100-continue) header, so I thought it is useful for my request to interrupt and manipulate the request. can anyone please suggest how to implement this logic's in my java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible via Filter Interface, you need to implement the interface and do your logic inside the doFilter method as per below code sample.

```
public class HttpFilter implements Filter
{
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
       FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException
   {
       HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;        
       if(httpRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("PUT")){

       }
       filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
   }
    // other methods etc
}
```

Then you need to make sure you declare your filter and filter-mapping entries inside web.xml

Comment: Thank you so much @johnII. Your suggestion works with the HttpSerlvet handler.

I am trying to develop a server using Jetty by extending AbstractHandler. Is there any way to interpret the 'Expect: 100 continue' requests in subclass of AbstractHandler?

There is an fix I saw in jetty but not sure is there any way to implement those in subclass of AbstracHandler.

(https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/277)